# AngularUI Modal controller error

Tags: angularjs

This is the first time I tried AngularUI Modal.

There is a constant error: `controller as vm` is not a function, got undefined.

Here is my Partial:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="controller as vm">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="hello.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    hello
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="vm.ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="vm.cancel()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.open()">Open me!</button>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('controller',[function($uibModal,$log)
{
var vm = this;
vm.animationsEnabled = true;

vm.open = function () {
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: vm.animationsEnabled,
  ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
  ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
  templateUrl: 'hello.html',
  controller: 'Modalcontroller',
  //controllerAs: 'vm',


  })
 };
}]);
```

app.js

```
var app=angular.module("myapp",['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

...

  .state("user", {
    url: "/user",
    views: {
      "main": {
        templateUrl: "partials/user.html",
        controller: "controller",
        controllerAs: "vm",
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? And why d you use the same controller for the enclosing page view, and the modal? That doesn't make much sense. In addition, since the controller is already specified in the state definition, specifying it again in the view will create two instances instead of just one. Remove it from the view.

Comment: I am using angular 1.5 and also edited accordingly as you said. What should i do further as the problem is not resolved yet

Comment: Replace `[function($uibModal,$log)` by `function($uibModal,$log)` or by `['$uibModal', '$log', function($uibModal,$log)`. Prefarrably the first one, and use ng-annotate to automatically transform to the second form during the build if you need minification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created the plunkr. Please have a look

```
(https://plnkr.co/edit/6fx26BVrXu0ud8TkvrMq?p=preview)

myApp.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', '$uibModal', '$state', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $uibModal, $state) {
        var self = this;
        self.cancel = function(){
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
        };

    }]);
     myApp.controller('userController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', '$state', function($scope, $uibModal, $state) {
        var self = this;
        self.animationsEnabled = true;

        self.open = function(){

         var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              animation: self.animationsEnabled,
              ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
              ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
              templateUrl: 'hello.html',
              controller: 'ModalController',
              controllerAs: 'vm'

          });
        };
    }]);
```